# Why does Success[...][key] work and Failure[...][key] doesn't work?

Tags: syntax, core-language, built-in-symbols, error-propagation

I'm trying to figure out what is a quick way to add error reporting to my user defined functions. I was experimenting with `Success` and `Failure` until I stumbled upon what seems to me an oddity of sorts. The examples are taken from the *Documentation Center*:

```
f = Failure["ExternalOperation", <|
  "MessageTemplate" -> "External operation `1` failed.", 
  "MessageParameters" -> {"file upload"}, 
  "File" -> "MyFile.wl"|>];
```

and

```
s = Success["MailSent", <|
  "MessageTemplate" :> "Mail sent to `recipient`.", 
  "MessageParameters" -> <|"recipient" -> "you@wolfram.com"|>, 
  "Sender" -> "me@wolfram.com", "Recipient" -> "you@wolfram.com", 
  "MessageID" -> "4ac4dsdasd483k28d4"|>];
```

In my code I found really useful the fact that it was possible to use something like `s["Sender"]` and obtain the desired result `"me@wolfram.com"`. That way, you could pass results and other information inside the `Success` wrapper.

Now, the odd thing is that such is not the case with `Failure`. Trying to evaluate `f["File"]` will not return `"MyFile.wl"` as I'd expect, but will return the `Failure` wrapper with the supplied key, like in `Failure[...]["File"]`.

I understand it is possible to obtain the desired result using something like `Extract[f, {2, Key["File"]}]` but I'd rather use the `f["File"]` approach, if that were possible.

My question is, why do `Failure` and `Success` behave differently despite the fact they *appear* to implement the same underlying interface in their definitions?

If I am wrong to anticipate that they should behave similarly, what am I missing? Is there something inherent in the way `Failure` is implemented that makes it *different*?

-- **Edit** --

It appears that it's no longer an issue in v.12. That's very thoughtful of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89812/discussion-on-question-by-user42582-why-does-success-key-work-and-failure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not work because it was not implemented, imo by omission. What was implemented is an overloaded `Part`:

```
f[["File"]]
```

> "MyFile.wl"

It won't work for `Success` though :)

What works for both of them is:

```
f[[2, "File"]]
s[[2, "Sender"]]
```

> "MyFile.wl"
>
> "me@wolfram.com"